# Like function in parameter stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Good day 
  I have problem with my store procedure as follow:

I need to know wchich manager have which employee
  My statement with function WITH as SELECT working fine ,but 
  my problem is with procedure when iam caling back Iam geting 0 rows back.
  I think should by problem with Function LIKE when Iam creating procerure.

Thank you for opinions

```
create procedure test @Name varchar(200) as

WITH n(Surname,Name) AS 
   (SELECT Surname,Name
    FROM [dbo].[phonebook]
    WHERE Name like '%@Name' --I need to be like here beause before name is XT245*/ SUBCODE
        UNION ALL
    SELECT subs.Surname, subs.Name
    FROM [dbo].[phonebook] as subs, n
    WHERE n.Surname = subs.Boss)
SELECT  Name FROM n 

exec test 'XX37485*/John'
```

Comment: You didn't use a parameter. You used a string that contains the characters %, @, N, a, m, e. Use `'%' + @Name` instead. Of course, you should know this will be *very* slow as `%whatever` can't take advantage of indexing.

Comment: Like @name will do, do not enclose it in single quotes

Comment: Thats mean i need to put LIKE function when Iam creating procedure?

Comment: If the name contains non-name data, you have a serious bug anyway. One field should contain one kind of info. That's the *MOST* fundamental design rule - 1 Normal Form. Fix the database and you *won't* need such quirky queries or have to deal with bad performance

Comment: @Ven it won't it will act just like `=` unless the parameter contains `%` characters

Comment: @Tester no, it means you should fix the database bug and only store names in the name field, not codes. Store codes in a different field

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i agree , that is not a better way of storing data, unless OP uses left or right to get data

Answer (score 0):

This expression:

WHERE Name like '%@Name' --I need to be like here because before name is XT245*/ SUBCODE

is looking for names that have *exactly* that pattern of characters . . . `@   N   a   m    e`.  There is no variable substitution.

If you want to use `like`, then:

```
WHERE Name like '%' + @Name
```

Note that this requires that the pattern *end* with `@Name`, so it will not match `@Name` anywhere in the string.